# Gui designer for java

Tags: java

i need a free tool like **Jform designer** or free plug-in for intelliJ idea to make gui form easier! az a mather o fact gui design in intelliJ idea is not good enough for me!i can't use it easy and i do'nt want to writing code for its weakness or use netbeans!i need solution for it!??
thanks very very much

Comment: a lot of people want more power :D try rephrasing your question, I guess you are simply looking for a good GUI Designer. But that question cannot be answered easily, especially since you don't give any criteria to "rate" different designers...

Answer (score 5):

Netbeans has one, [it's called Matisse](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html).

Eclipse has a number of them, the only one I'm remotely familiar with is [Window Builder](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html).

Comment: Note that when using the Netbeans one you basically *force* the use of Netbeans for anyone who comes after you to maintain the code. The code doesn't lend itself well to be edited by hand.

Comment: While you are correct, I've yet to see a GUI design tool that really facilitates hand editing and maintains ability to redesign (out of tool).

Comment: Edwin: WPF's XAML comes pretty close, actually. It's XML, so it allows direct nesting without too much hassle and the GUI editor of Visual Studio produces pretty much the same XML that you'd write by hand. I find myself doing hand-writing and using the designer about the same amount of time. Of course, there are at least 10 years between WPF and Swing, so it comes as no surprise that people have learned from mistakes :-)

Comment: If I use Eclipse, Jigloo GUI Builder for Eclipse will be sufficient...it can read Netbean .form-generated java file as well http://www.cloudgarden.com/jigloo/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use NetBeans IDE:

http://netbeans.org/downloads/

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html

Answer (score 1):

Google recently donated the former proprietary GUI designer WindowBuilder to the Eclipse foundation. It's a great tool, check it out:
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/javadevtools/wbpro/

Some of its features include:

- Bi-directional Code Generation - read and write almost any format and reverse-engineer most hand-written code
- Internationalization (i18n) / Localization - externalize component strings, create and manage resource bundles.
- Custom Composites & Panels - create custom, reusable components.
- Factories - create custom factory classes and methods.
- Visual Inheritance - create visual component hierarchies.
- Event Handling - add event handlers to your components.
- Menu Editing - visually create and edit menubars, menu items and popup menus.
- Morphing - convert one component type into another.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing what everyone else has said about Netbeans. It has been wonderful to me for wiring up forms, but after that hand coding has been the way I go thereafter.  I typically structure my classes as follows:

```
public class MyPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel
{
    public MyPanel(...)
    {
       initComponents();
       build();
       initListeners();
    }
 }
```

where initComponents() is the autogenerated layout from NetBeans. Then I add any additional components in my build() which I want to either hand code or set default params that I didn't want to do in the form designer, and then add my listeners in another hand coded method, initListeners(). That way even I'm not stuck in Netbeans, when I move away from it for further development (which I do in Eclipse).  The downside is that I have two IDEs.